# Folder names and file names text is wrapping

Tags: 20.04, gnome, nautilus, files

New to Ubuntu! Coming from too many years on the Apple tit. Glad to be here.

Love everything about my Ubunutu experience except one major pet peave...

File names and folder names - the text wraps down to the next line and it is visually distracting and, frankly, horrible to read.

How do I stop the text from wrapping? Letters of the same word should not push down to a second line.

What I see:

Folde

r Na

me

What I want:

Folder

Name

or

Folder Name

[Example screenshot - the letters 'nts' in the name 'Documents' should not push down or wrap to a second line of text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GHCw.png)

How the heck do I stop this text and character wrapping? Running stock Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, Gnome 3.36.8, Window System X11.

Answer (score 1):

It is ugly indeed, but it is how it works if your icons are set to a rather small size. To avoid the issue, enlarge the icons somewhat: hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>.

There is also a "List" view, which you can try.

Comment: Ok, so that *sorta* worked. There are less file and folder names being wrapped to the next line but it's still happening. Thanks for the feedback.

Hopefully there is another solution someone might know of.

Comment: That can be hoped, but I am afraid that the only way is to file an issue with the developpers (probably exists already) or edit source code yourself.